# Custom Game Center GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, gkturnbasedmatch

I'm trying to create a custom view controller to display active games to the user (similar to what Letterpress does).

I am currently trying to subclass GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController except I don't know how to hide the default elements (for inviting/showing existing games) and to add my own. I have currently been playing around with logging things to ensure I can access the active matches, current player IDs, etc (which I have recently figured out) but I am stuck on how to start with the interface.

Not sure what code, if any would be relevant at this point. Please let me know.

Looking to: Hide current elements. I'm assuming I can build the interface as I would for any other application after that.

Thanks,

- Steven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its a good idea to subclass. Start with a clean UIViewController and build the UI from there. Then implement all the necessary methods.

Set yourself as delegate:

```
   [GKTurnBasedEventHandler sharedTurnBasedEventHandler].delegate = self;
```

so you get delegate event, such as:

```
handleInviteFromGameCenter
handleTurnEventForMatch
handleMatchEnded
etc.
```

Add a UITableView, and load all matches from Game center:

```
   [GKTurnBasedMatch loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *matches, NSError *error) {
     // Add matches to table view
   }];
```

Don't forget to authenticate the player first:

```
GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *loginVC, NSError *error)
{

};
```

Star a match programatically:

```
GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
request.minPlayers = 2;
request.maxPlayers = 2;
[GKTurnBasedMatch findMatchForRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(GKTurnBasedMatch *match, NSError *error)
 {

 }];
```

etc. Look at the doc for the full API.

Comment: How do you suggest I load a match programatically, from the tableView:didSelectRow method?

Comment: You don't. Call loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler, and you get back all the matches. You then save the array of matches in an ivar, and populate the tableView from that.